# Solve $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{(1+x)^{1/x}}-(1+x)^{\frac{e}{x}}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{(1+x)^{1/x}}-(1+x)^{\frac{e}{x}}}{x^2}$$
I've tried the L'Hôpital's Rule, but failed.
Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm quite interested in your problem, could please contact me with zhushuierjirou@gmail.com or 13777359367?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use  L'Hôpital's rule. Let $$f(x)=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=e$$

Also $$f'(x)=f(x)\:\frac{x-ln(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)}$$ so

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=e \times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-ln(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)}=\frac{e}{2}$$

Now $$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{f(x)}-f(x)^e}{x^2}$$ Using L'Hôpital's Rule

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) \times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{f(x)}-ef(x)^{e-1}}{2x}=\frac{e}{2} \times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{f(x)}-ef(x)^{e-1}}{2x}$$  $\implies$

$$L=\frac{e^2}{4}\times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{f(x)-1}-f(x)^{e-1}}{x}$$ Again applying L'Hôpital's Rule

$$L=\frac{e^2}{4} \times \lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) \times \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{f(x)-1}-(e-1)f(x)^{e-2}}{1}$$ $\implies$

$$L=\frac{e^2}{4} \times \frac{e}{2} \times \left(e^{e-1}-(e-1)e^{e-2}\right)=\frac{e^{e+1}}{8}$$

Comment: Very good answer. +1

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks.

Comment: Nice!  However, I believe that your expression for $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f^\prime(x) $ should have $ (1 + x) \log (1 + x) $ rather than just $ \log (1 + x) $, which yields a limit of $ -e / 2$.  Since you pull that factor out twice, you still end up with the same answer :).

Answer (score 5):

Do the Taylor Expansion around $x=0$, then you get:
$$
e^{(1+x)^{1/x}}-(1+x)^{\frac{e}{x}}=\frac{1}{8} e^{1+e} x^2-\frac{1}{16} e^{1+e} (3+e) x^3+\mathcal{O}(x^4)
$$
Thus the answer is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{8}e^{1+e}$.

Comment: Thanks, I think Taylor Expansion is too hard and brute force if without computer, any other way?